# Creating a variable using conditionals python using vectorization

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below,

```
    flag a  b   c
0   1   5   1   3
1   1   2   1   3
2   1   3   0   3
3   1   4   0   3
4   1   5   5   3
5   1   6   0   3
6   1   7   0   3
7   2   6   1   4
8   2   2   1   4
9   2   3   1   4
10  2   4   1   4
```

I want to create a column 'd' based on the below condition:

1) For first row of each flag, if a>c, then d = b, else d = nan

2) For non-first row of each flag, if (a>c) & ((previous row of d is nan) | (b > previous row of d)), d=b, else d = prev row of d

I am expecting the below output:

```
    flag a  b   c  d
0   1   5   1   3  1
1   1   2   1   3  1
2   1   3   0   3  1
3   1   4   0   3  1
4   1   5   5   3  5
5   1   6   0   3  5
6   1   7   0   3  5
7   2   6   1   4  1
8   2   2   1   4  1
9   2   3   1   4  1
10  2   4   1   4  1
```

Comment: You expected output is different from what you show , also I will suggested close (Accept the answer )your pervious question , keep 3 open questions is not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would translate your logic:

```
df['d'] = np.nan

# first row of flag
s = df.flag.ne(df.flag.shift())

# where a > c
a_gt_c = df['a'].gt(df['c'])

# fill the first rows with a > c
df.loc[s & a_gt_c, 'd'] = df['b']

# mask for second fill
mask = ((~s)                                # not first rows 
        & a_gt_c                            # a > c
        & (df['d'].shift().isna()           # previous d not null 
           | df['b'].gt(df['d']).shift())   # or b > previous d
       )

# fill those values:
df.loc[mask, 'd'] = df['b']

# ffill for the rest
df['d'] = df['d'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
    flag  a  b  c    d
0      1  5  1  3  1.0
1      1  2  1  3  1.0
2      1  3  0  3  1.0
3      1  4  0  3  0.0
4      1  5  5  3  5.0
5      1  6  0  3  0.0
6      1  7  0  3  0.0
7      2  6  1  4  1.0
8      2  2  1  4  1.0
9      2  3  1  4  1.0
10     2  4  1  4  1.0
```

Comment: Value of d for index 3 should be 1 because, it doesnot fulfil "(a>c) & ((previous row of d is nan) | (b > previous row of d))" condition so d = previous value of d which is 1

Comment: Also index 5 and 6 needs to be 5 following the same condition

Comment: They do satisfy `df['d'].shift().isna()`, before you fill row 2. Other way could be possible, but tbh, your question wasn't that clear.

Comment: But in row 2 , we assigned nan to the new variable based on 1st line of code, it does not come based on 1 step. I have updated my question